# Javascript writing to a text file on multiple lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I am coding something that pulls a json file off a url and parses the json.
The script can filter out the data that I need and it works just fine.

Now, my goal is to have the data be written to a text file. I have achieved this, but the data is cluttered onto one line. I have posted my code below.

```js
document.getElementById("find").addEventListener("click", sendHTTP);

function sendHTTP() 
{
    var httpreq;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else 
    { // code for IE6, IE5
        httpreq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    httpreq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpreq.readyState == 4) 
        {
            var store = httpreq.responseText;
            var me = JSON.parse(store);
            var parsed = [];
            try  
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < store.length; i++) 
                {
                    parsed.push(me.products[i].title);    // title

                    for (var j = 0; j < me.products[i].offers.length; j++) 
                    {
                        parsed.push(me.products[i].offers[j].offer_id);  // offer_id
                    }
                }
            } 
            catch (err) 
            { } 
            finally 
            {
                downloadURI("data:text/html," + parsed.join(""), "inventory.txt");
            }
        }
    };

    httpreq.open("GET", "http://shop.cncpts.com/collections/nike-sb.oembed");
    httpreq.send();
}

function downloadURI(uri, name) 
{
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    link.click();
}
```

The function downloadURI performs the download.
The text file will successfully download, but the data from the json is cluttered to one line.

Is there any possible way that I could make everything go on a separate line? For example:

title
offer_id
title
offer_id.....

Comment: `parsed.join("\r\n")` might get you somewhere

Comment: @Jack: You mean `.join('\r\n')` for sure?

Comment: @Bergi assuming you saw my comment before I saw my mistake :P

Comment: Maybe I should start answering questions instead of useful comments :)

Comment: @Jack: Yes indeed. (to both of them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join with newlines

```
downloadURI("data:text/html," + encodeURIComponent(parsed.join("\r\n"), "inventory.txt"));
```

Comment: Do you need to `encodeURIComponent` as well? Having a real new line in a URL seems wrong to me

Comment: @PaulS. - Aha, that's whats missing, I was testing and just couldn't get it working, but the string has to be encoded, but the `data` part can't be encoded

Comment: And for windows it actually *has*  to be linefeed + carriage return (`\r\n`) or it won't work either.

Comment: @adeneo Thank you! Works perfect. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @adeneo carriage `\r` eturn + li `\n` e feed, `CrLf`, `\r\n`. Always saying them in the correct order makes life easier (although I know the easy way to remember of `\r` etur `\n` )

Comment: @PaulS. - I always remember `\n` being "newline", i.e. a carriage return, but still manage to mix them up sometimes, like above, mostly because it confuses me, but I always get them in the right order when typing them in JS.

Comment: @adeneo I think `\r` is the "move to the beginning of the line" and `\n` is the "move down", and the order comes from typewriters where you'd push the thing across and thus it'd use the sideways motion to scroll the paper a bit at the same time? It's still confusing though, I accept.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

`downloadURI("data:text/html," + parsed.join("\r\n"), "inventory.txt");`